# how I can run this piece of code on paper?

Tags: c++

this piece of code is complicated for me.

```
int main()
{
   int n;
     cin>>n;
     n=n/100*100+n%100/10+n%10*10;
     cout<<n;
}
```

how I can trace this piece of code in C++, I don't know which operator acts first.

Comment: Have a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: You should look up "c++ operator precedence" next time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to resolve it all it takes is a single link to an off-site resource.

Comment: I looked that table, but when I run the program the result is not consistent with the paper result. for example in the first n/100*100, first * acts then /. am I right?

Comment: @MichaelVlach *'Multiplication and division order in that part does not matter (the outcome would be the same either way).'* Wrong! Multiplication and division order does matter. For example `n/100` equals ZERO for `n == 13` and further `*100` will NOT recover the `13` value. Even worse, If you reversed the order the expression would be equivalent to `n/(100*100)` that is `n/10000`....

Comment: @MichaelVlach that is *not* true. Integer operation of  `n/100*100` as `(n/100)*100` vs. `n/(100*100)` (effectively `n/10000`) are *not* equivalent.

Comment: I recommend you always use parentheses `(` and `)` to express the intended order of evaluation.

Comment: @Galik Please note the OP didn't write the expression but rather tries to understand it. Anyway the operators' priorities and associativity were invented just to avoid tons of parentheses.

Comment: @StoryTeller: There is nothing wrong with simple questions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You and I clearly have different opinions about the merit of this question. And seeing as SE is an awesome platform, we are both entitled to them. So long as we aren't rude, which I believe I wasn't.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You were not. I have just seen people closing questions as "too simple", however "simple" is in the eye of the beholder. Similarly, saying that "a single link to an offsite resource is sufficient" may be true, but it does not mean the question does not have its place on stackoverflow (contrary to a link to a duplicate). StackOverflow aims at being the end-all be-all of Q&A, so that any question simple enough to be answered on the site should have an answer on the site. This question fits within those parameters.

Comment: @MatthieuM., maybe. But one quality that I noticed is always frowned upon in SO questions is the lack of prior research. This is hardly the case when one is faced with a wall of standardese, and asks a seemingly "simple" question.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Lack of prior research is cause for downvoting but I find it a stretch to use it for closing :)

Comment: **HOW** on Earth the question about **semantics of an expression** in the C or C++ **programming language** is _not about programming_!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the **sum of the 3 parts**:

```
temp1 = n     / 100;    # it is integer division (decimal part is throwing out)
temp1 = temp1 * 100;

temp2 = n     % 100;    # remainder after division by 100, i. e. last 2 digits
temp2 = temp2 /  10;

temp3 = n     %  10;    # remainder after division by  10, i. e. last digit
temp3 = temp3 *  10;

n     = temp1 + temp2 + temp3;
```

Comment: Your answer lacks one step: the order of summation: `temp4 =  temp1 + temp2; n = temp4 + temp3;`

Answer (score 2):

See e.g.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Divisions and multiplications are done first, from left to right:

```
n = ((n/100) * 100) + ((n%100) / 10) +  ((n%10) * 10)
    ^-------------^   ^------------^    ^-----------^
```

then additions are done from left to right:

```
n = ( (  ((n/100) * 100) + ((n%100) / 10) ) +  ((n%10) * 10) )
    | ^-----------------------------------^                  |
    +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

and finally the assignment.